# Selenium testing setup on remote server

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, selenium, drupal

I'm trying to install and run Selenium on a remote server to run web tests for a Drupal 7 install.  I need to find a way for the browsers installed on the server to output their display onto the computer that is connected to the server, and I need to figure out why Selenium is failing to run.  Error messages down below.

### My server set up:

- centOS 7.1 on Linux running NGinX web server
- X11Forwarding available and enabled
- Drupal 7 install
- Selenium 7.x-3.0 Drupal Module
- Selenium Standalone Server 2.46.0
- Firefox 38.1.0 installed
- Google Chrome stable 43.0.2357.132
- Chromedriver 2.16 for 64-bit Linux, set to executable, with symlink to driver in /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin (the local is the only necessary one, the usr/bin is just a fallback)

Note: my solution *must* have the server hosting the selenium server as the website will be delivered to a client when it's ready for production.  It won't work for me to just install the selenium server and browsers on my own machine.

### My issues:

- When I ssh -X user@server, it doesn't seem to matter what I set the DISPLAY to, firefox can't open the display when I run 'firefox &' [e1].  I've tried export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0, localhost:10.0 and [myIP]:0.0/10.0.
- When I run the selenium server and attempt to run the sample test cases on my website, the Firefox instance of the test fails to connect through 127.0.0.1 port 7055 [e2] and the Chrome instance is either unable to find the driver or shuts down unexpectedly [e3]

### Errors:

- **e1** - Error: cannot open display: host:#.#   <== (Whatever variant I've attempted)
- **e2** - Message: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output: (blank)
- **e3** - Message: chrome not reachable

SimpleTest isn't a suitable replacement as the things I'm trying to test require too much custom setup to configure a stock Drupal sandbox properly. Consequently, I'm relying on Selenium's option to test on the original site instead of a sandbox.

Comment: on the display problem, you have to run an X server (such as Xvfb) and export the DISPLAY variable to whatever the display you set up.

Comment: Does Xvfb normally take a really long time to initialize?  Got it installed fine, but when I run "Xvfb :1 -screen 0 800x600x16" it never seems to finish initializing all its components.  Or maybe I'm just impatient?

Comment: It's not a 'finishing' process, it'll continuously run in the background. You can regain control of your terminal with ```Xvfb :1 -screen 0 800x600x16 &``` (The ampersand at the end of the line) although occasionally funny things will pop up, but you can just ignore it.

Comment: +1 Lawrence, Xvfb works fine and, while my problem is still not completely fixed, this got me a couple steps closer.  Will update my question